# Function Returning Multiple Values SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been trying to return 2 values from a function in PL/SQL . The first value i want it to be the salary of the guy i have to search for. The second i want it to be the number of rows affected by this. I searched google for a while and i found out that i must first make a type so that i can return the data. However i get an error :

```
Error(9,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,36): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

The code that i have is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE return_type AS OBJECT(val1 NUMBER,val2 NUMBER);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2
(v_nume employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell')
RETURN return_type IS

out_var return_type;
salariu employees.salary%type;

BEGIN

SELECT salary INTO salariu
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = v_nume;

INSERT INTO out_var values(salariu,@@ROWCOUNT);

RETURN out_var;

EXCEPTION

WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Nu exista angajati cu numele dat');
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Exista mai multi angajati cu numele dat');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Alta eroare!');
END f2;
/
```

Comment: Replace also the `INSERT INTO out_var values(salariu,@@ROWCOUNT);` with the assignment statements `out_var.val1 := salariu;
       out_var.val1 := 1;`, you can't insert values into object, in case of pl/sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2
(v_nume employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell',
 nr OUT employees.salary%TYPE )
RETURN NUMBER IS

salariu employees.salary%type;

BEGIN

SELECT salary INTO salariu
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = v_nume;
nr := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
RETURN salariu;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
'Nu exista angajati cu numele dat');
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
'Exista mai multi angajati cu numele dat');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Alta eroare!');
END f2;
/
```

Comment: `nr` is meaningless in this scenario: it will always be on`1`. Any other case results in an exception thrown (no data found, or too many rows).

Comment: yes, i do realise that :D however this function will be further developed and nr will have a role there

Comment: thank you very much for both your interest and your good wishes :P